# Unable to access GitHub from Windows

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to keeping a fork up to date and following the steps [here](https://gist.github.com/CristinaSolana/1885435).

On first step I've tried

```
git clone git@github.com:isaaclem/react-native-calendars.git
```

And below is the feedback I've got
[image]

I thought it has something to do with profile not being configured so I've

```
git config --global user.name "xxx"
git config --global user.email "xxx"
```

Below is the full list of configuration, not sure if it helps

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
credential.helper=manager
user.name=*masked*
user.email=*masked*
```

What else can I try or which directions can I heading to in order to clone them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to clone repo with SSH, you must generate SSH key and add to GitHub.
But if you are cloning with HTTPS you should create credential with `git config credential.helper 'store [options]'`

Read from here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Answer (score 1):

You must create ssh key and register public key to github.